# IIS Session isolation problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2007, iis-6

I am using `ShDocVW.InternetExplorer` class to spawn a new internet explorer object and to do some form filling stuffs(for some sharepoint works).It works fine in my own machine which has Windows 7 as the OS. But when I deployed the same thing in windows server 2003 machine, it does not pop up the internet explorer window. When I check the Task Manager, I could see a new iexplore process, but with Session ID = 0 (but session ID = 1 in windows 7). So, I see this is something regarding IIS Session isolation.So, is it possible to assign a `ShDocVW.InternetExplorer` instance to kind of a new `System.Diagnostics.Process` and achieve this task? Or can we start a new ShDocVW.InternetExplorer instance with session ID = 1?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to start IE to fill out a form? Why don't you just programatically post the values?

Comment: Because I need to find the status of the returned web page after form filling stuff... which is done by analysing at the DocumentCompleted method in `shDocVw.internetexplorer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yap... I got the answer to the problem, In IIS we cannot spawn processes using Shell Execution with the default settings... If we need to do so, there are 2 workarounds that need to be set which can be found from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555134). And by the way, thanx very much for you guys' input and support which helps me to figure this out. cheers...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear on what you are doing but if the app that spawns the ShDocVW.InternetExplorer process is an ASP.NET app then you won't see the window because IIS runs as a windows service and as such Windows Services use a different "desktop" than the desktop you're logged in as. So you'll never see any windows and Windows service application launches.

I think what you should do is create a GUI applications that instantiates your explorer window.

Comment: But What I want is to spawn a new Internet explorer instance when I click a control in the aspx page.

Comment: On the server or the client? If the code that creates an instance of ShDocW is server side code then you're creating it in the process space of the server process which is IIS and which as I explained earlier is a Windows service and as such you will never see that instance of IE

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is that you are trying to do something through code, and since this will work on the server you will see a process getting spawned on the server... AND NOT on the client as you are assuming. It is working on your dev machine, since you would have been using FileSystem for your project and your project's pages are being served by cassini - Web Development Server which launches on your own machine.

The approach of filling out the form is wrong. You should be using POST request and read the values on the server for doing necessary processing of the data that has been posted.