# I want execute .exe file on IIS server through ASP web page btnClick, im using Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath(@"~\\bin\\HelloApp.exe");
        process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        process1.Start();
        process1.WaitForExit();
        process1.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this?

Comment: This is my task im fresher in ASP.NET all works fine with local machine but  not with IIS server

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No im not getting any error

Comment: Is `HelloApp` a graphical application?

Comment: I Want to  execute .exe on btnClick from IIS server

Comment: no its a console app,

Comment: ihave created helloApp.exe and paste in in my project bin folder

Comment: What does the properties `ExitCode`, `StandardOutput` and `StandardInput` of `process1` contain?

Comment: i dont know about it,im fresher can you please tell me right answer and how i do this

Answer (score 0):

try this code and see if you get any error. if you get an error check whether the published code bin has the HelloApp.exe.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileNameWithPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"~\\bin\\HelloApp.exe");
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.Arguments = "";
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

        startInfo.FileName = fileNameWithPath;

            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                StreamReader outputReader = exeProcess.StandardOutput;
                StreamReader errorReader = exeProcess.StandardError;
                string errors = errorReader.ReadToEnd();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errors))
                    throw new Exception(errors);
            }

    }
```

Comment: No it raising error "System cannot find path specified.

Comment: error at startInfo  but path is correect , path is in my system as below: E:\Codding 2\Practice\ASP\MyTaskExe\MyTaskExe\bin\HelloApp.exe

Comment: ok now try giving the full path instead of just "~\\bin\\HelloApp.exe", if you are able to execute it that way then the relative path you have mentioned is wrong.

Comment: After running it localy it runs fine but when i click on close exe is raises : StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet. this error

Comment: also getting this error : StandardError has not been redirected.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to call another UI application by the application hosted in IIS. Due to the fact that there is no user session to render the UI. Since Windows Vista, there is a mechanic called Session Isolation, which separates the application and the service.
However, it will work when we start the application by Visual Studio locally since the current session is inherited with the account running Visual Studio.
For details, please refer to the below links.
[How to start a process from an IIS hosted WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209505/how-to-start-a-process-from-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service)
[IIS Session isolation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141147/iis-session-isolation-problem)